# how to scroll a canvas with pictures in python?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

I tried to scroll a column of images in a canvas with code bellow, when I run the code, the scrollbar shows up but has nothing to scroll. and images are in the main directory.

CODE(python 3):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='#1d1d1d')
root.geometry('100x200')
f = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'folder.png')
d = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'database.png')

can = tk.Canvas(root , bg = 'red' )
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root  , command=can.yview)

for i in range(20):
  tk.Label(can , image = f , anchor = 'w').pack( side = 'top')
for i in range(10):
  tk.Label(can , image = d , anchor = 'w').pack( side = 'top')

can.pack( side = 'left')
scroll.pack(side = 'right' , fill = 'y')
can.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
can.configure(scrollregion=can.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas cannot scroll items added with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. To add something to the canvas that can be scrolled you must use one of the `create_*` methods (`create_window`, `create_image`, etc).